# Can we rotate an image in MATLAB filled with background color of original image?

Tags: matlab, rotation, image-rotation

By default, MATLAB function imrotate rotate image with black color filled in rotated portion. See this,  http://in.mathworks.com/help/examples/images_product/RotationFitgeotransExample_02.png

We can have rotated image with  [white background](http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/10089-image-rotate) also.

Question is, Can we rotate an image (with or without using imrotate) filled with background of original image?

Specific to my problem: Colored image with very small angle of rotation (<=5 deg.)

Comment: Well what would you define the background color of this image?

Comment: @knedlsepp: I want to fill it with background of original image.

Comment: You should reformulate your question then. "Filled with background color of original image." is not the same as: "The background should be the original image."

Comment: @knedlsepp: Already specified it. Please check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a naive approach, where we simply apply the same rotation to a mask and take only the parts of the rotated image, that correspond to the transformed mask. Then we just superimpose these pixels on the original image.
I ignore possible blending on the boundary.

```
A = imread('cameraman.tif');
angle = 10;
T = @(I) imrotate(I,angle,'bilinear','crop');
%// Apply transformation
TA = T(A);
mask = T(ones(size(A)))==1;
A(mask) = TA(mask);
%%// Show image
imshow(A);
```

[image: Cameraman rotated]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your code gives same size image as original and seems to be working fine for small angle of rotation.

Comment: How we can achieve the same effect on different kind of transformation (e.g. shear)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`padarray()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html) function with `'replicate'` and `'both'` option to interpolate your image. Then you can use `imrotate()` function.

In the code below, I've used `ceil(size(im)/2)` as pad size; but you may want bigger pad size to eliminate the black part. Also I've used `s` and `S`( writing `imR(S(1)-s(1):S(1)+s(1), S(2)-s(2):S(2)+s(2), :)`) to crop the image where you can extract bigger part of image just expanding boundary of index I used below for `imR`.

Try this:

```
im  = imread('cameraman.tif'); %// You can also read a color image 
s   = ceil(size(im)/2);
imP = padarray(im, s(1:2), 'replicate', 'both');
imR = imrotate(imP, 45);
S   = ceil(size(imR)/2);
imF = imR(S(1)-s(1):S(1)+s(1)-1, S(2)-s(2):S(2)+s(2)-1, :); %// Final form
figure, 
subplot(1, 2, 1)
imshow(im); 
title('Original Image')
subplot(1, 2, 2)
imshow(imF);
title('Rotated Image')
```

This gives the output below:

[image]

Not so good but better than black thing..

Comment: What in case of colored image?

Comment: The size of final image is not almost same (difference of 2-3 pixel) as original image. Can we control it?

Comment: @user11659 - Of course you can. But the thing is that if you want the size of final image same with original image, you should realize you would lose same details especially in the corner part. Difference of 1 pixel for each edge is caused from extracting middle part of rotated image. You know, the formula of number of element is "(finalValue-initialValue)/increment - 1", according to this formula, in my code, minus one is missing.. I would have edited my answer. Good luck...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Still size of final image is not exactly same (diff. of 1 pix) , in case of odd no. of (height/width) pixels in original image.